# Entity Framework FirstOrDefault predicate not returning expected results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm learning C# and ASP.NET Core.

I have a model class with a key of type `Guid`:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and I have a repository with a database context. I'm trying to search by this Guid, but I'm unable to find any results.

```
public Product GetProductById(Guid id) 
{
    foreach (var product in _context.Products.ToList()) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("id: {0}, search: {1}, match: {2}", product.Id, id, product.Id == id);
    }

    return _context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

The above method outputs the following, but returns a null `Product`.

```
id: ad253f3e-bf32-4b17-a667-4de1c70175be, search: 80e0ca0a-fbec-495a-b008-557586511de0, match: False
id: 80e0ca0a-fbec-495a-b008-557586511de0, search: 80e0ca0a-fbec-495a-b008-557586511de0, match: True
id: da51a147-4b28-48a1-8b0a-fe7876df6a58, search: 80e0ca0a-fbec-495a-b008-557586511de0, match: False
id: 786f1c64-815f-4e80-a441-e5ea09ad16ca, search: 80e0ca0a-fbec-495a-b008-557586511de0, match: False
id: 81bbbb96-1290-479b-9cf6-e18b21500d71, search: 80e0ca0a-fbec-495a-b008-557586511de0, match: False
```

Is there some mistake I'm making or issue with my query?

**Edit** David in the comments asked for some additional info.

SQL query from logs:

```
dbug: 12/8/2021 15:10:01.496 RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpening[20000] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection) 
      Opening connection to database 'main' on server 'refactored.db'.

dbug: 12/8/2021 15:10:01.518 RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpened[20001] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection) 
      Opened connection to database 'main' on server '/home/kevin/Desktop/XeroApplication/RefactoredProject/src/Refactored/refactored.db'.

dbug: 12/8/2021 15:10:01.532 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting[20100] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__id_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT "p"."Id", "p"."DeliveryPrice", "p"."Description", "p"."Name", "p"."Price"
      FROM "Products" AS "p"
      WHERE "p"."Id" = @__id_0
      LIMIT 1

info: 12/8/2021 15:10:01.563 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (33ms) [Parameters=[@__id_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT "p"."Id", "p"."DeliveryPrice", "p"."Description", "p"."Name", "p"."Price"
      FROM "Products" AS "p"
      WHERE "p"."Id" = @__id_0
      LIMIT 1
      
dbug: 12/8/2021 15:10:01.571 RelationalEventId.DataReaderDisposing[20300] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      A data reader was disposed.
```

and the schema of the table from SQLite

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Products" (
    "Id" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Products" PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Description" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Price" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "DeliveryPrice" TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: looks correct to me, unless it's issue with lazy loading of data

Comment: Does it still return a `null` product if you comment out the loop? (i.e: if you comment the `.ToList()` call)

Comment: What database?  Can you post the table DDL and the SQL query generated by logging? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging

Comment: Rafalon, I'm using SQLite. David, have added that info to the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
 return _context.Products
    .Where((p => p.Id.ToString() == id.ToString())
    .FirstOrDefault)
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad but I ran into this error with this implementation
`
 System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Product>()
          .Where(p => p.Id.ToString() == __ToString_0)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'object.ToString' failed.`

Comment: what  version of EF is you using?